# How can I align elements between two DIVs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got two containers on my website ([Code for Good](http://www.codeforgood.info)) with a few elements in them.

How can I make the text paragraph, and the buttons align between them?

Comment: Without JsFiddle of your project, it will be hard to help you, because we don't know which elements you have to align, where do you want them exactly, what you have tried, etc. Please, link us a reference to your project in JsFiddle,

Comment: What is it that you need to align ? The elements on the site all look well aligned to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<h2>` for `Designers and Developers` is taller because the text wraps.  Remove the empty `<h2>` that is under `Charities` and set `height: 80px` (the height of "Designers and Developers") and everything seems to line up okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are on the same place of the divs, so that's not the problem.
The problem is the whole div itself.

The Design div and Charity div have a different height (580 and 590)
Make it both the same and the buttons will become the same, same as the text itself. (if you have coded it well)

Answer (score 0):

I added a `margin-top:20px;` to the first `p` in Charities div and everything seems to align perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using 4 divs: two of them are for the actual text and details. The other two are just containers for your buttons. Set a fixed height for the two text divs.

```
<div id="left">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
    <p>Details are here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div>Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
    <p>Details are here, and are much longer than the ones in the first div so that the text wraps.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div>Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left, #right {
  width : 50%;
}

.text {
  height: 400px; // Or any fixed size that makes sense
}
```

If you end up nesting two many divs with fixed sizes you should consider using tables, or use grid systems like the one provided with [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).